# variable array in jquery returns [](brackets) value

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have this variable in jquery that gets the value of checked input radio button,

```
var gender = [];
    $("input[type='radio'][name='gender\\[$counter\\]']:checked").each(function ()
    {
        gender.push($(this).val());
    });       

    console.log(gender);
```

My input field looks like this,

```
<input id="gender" value="Male" name="gender[$counter]" type="radio" />
<input id="gender" value="Female" name="gender[$counter]" type="radio" />
```

But the console.log(gender); returns the value "[ ]" but not the value of that input field. What seems to be the problem? Please help.

Comment: none of the radio input is checked

Comment: Don't repeat ids.  Use a class, and use the class for your selector.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page

Comment: Yes but I'm the one that will checked it sir. For example I have checked the Male radio button ang submit but still I got the brackets return value from my console.log

Comment: Also, only one of these element can be checked at a given time.  They share the same name, so returning an array really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ohh I see. So what is your suggestion sir?

Comment: No need to do the each.  The selector will return 0 or 1 elements, and if it's 1, just use it

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined gender as an array []... therefore it is showing gender as an array [].

Why is gender an array? Gender is either none, male, or female.... not more than one. So start with

```
var gender = "";
```

Then no need to loop through the elements because only one will be checked. And just to be sure and avoid exceptions first check if a radio is checked or not:

```
if($("input[type='radio'][name='gender\\[$counter\\]']:checked").length > 0){    
   gender = $("input[type='radio'][name='gender\\[$counter\\]']:checked").val();
}
```